# Using pyenv, how can I pip install global CLIs and make them available even when in a virtualenv?

Tags: python, pip, pyenv

There are many pip-installed CLI's like `ansible` and `black` that I want to have access to always, no matter which python version or virtualenv I am using. If I mark a certain python installation as global (a la `pyenv global 3.10.0`), I can then use `pip` to install these CLI's into that global python's site-packages, and pyenv makes them runnable while I'm using the global python. However, they become unavailable once I'm inside a virtualenv. This makes me no longer able to use tools for linting, deploying, and doing generic system-related tasks without installing these tools into the virtualenv, which I do not want to do.

Is there a supported or common way of solving this problem so that I can install certain pip packages which include binaries, and have those binaries always accessible?

Comment: Try https://github.com/pypa/pipx, it's made for this sort of stuff.

Comment: @tzaman Thank you SO much. I came across this tool a few years ago and tried so hard recently to find it, but my google-fu was not strong enough. This is exactly what I was looking for! If you make this an answer I'll gladly accept it because it solves my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Python Packaging Authority](https://pypa.io) has a tool called [PipX](https://github.com/pypa/pipx) which is meant for exactly this purpose, check it out!

From the readme:

> **Overview: What is pipx?**
>
> pipx is a tool to help you install and run
> end-user applications written in Python. It's roughly similar to
> macOS's brew, JavaScript's npx, and Linux's apt.
>
> It's closely related to pip. In fact, it uses pip, but is focused on
> installing and managing Python packages that can be run from the
> command line directly as applications.